# EF Code First one-many relation both ways

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, data-annotations

I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, MaxLength(8)]
    public string Id                     { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public short DepartmentId            { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}


public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public short Id                      { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name                   { get; set; }
    public string ManagerUserId          { get; set; }

    public virtual User Manager          { get; set; }
}
```

I could not manage how to add the relations shown in the following diagram:

[image]

My main problem is adding the relation between `ManagerUserId` and the `User` entity. After doing some research I tried the following:

```
[ForeignKey("ManagerUserId")]
public virtual User Manager          { get; set; }
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'CheckFlights.User' and 'CheckFlights.Department'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

**Q: How do I get it to have the relation as in the diagram above? where the `Manager` property in the `Department` entity can be a user or be null? a user can be a manager for few departments at the same time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF tries to establish *a single one-to-one* relationship by convention between the two types because both navigation properties are references (not collections). But you actually want *two one-to-many* relationships. You must overwrite the default convention with Fluent API to achieve this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.Department)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.DepartmentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
    .HasOptional(d => d.Manager)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ManagerUserId);
```